# idea and intuition behind triangulated category

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

I have some trouble in understanding the significance of some axiom of triangulated category.

If someone could explain to me each axiom with some intuition, and explain to me the intuition behind the translation functor

I would be
very grateful !!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello.. Welcome to MO.. First, let’s start with the axiom you are having difficulty in understanding.. what is the axiom?

Comment: Thanks you for your answer,TR2-TR4 the most problematic is TR2 for the two other I have some intuition  @PraphullaKoushik

Comment: What do you mean by problematic?

Comment: no intuition about why this axiom ?

Comment: I do realize this is probably not helping, but I am strongly convinced that the only way to get reliable intuition for how triangulated categories work in practice is to get at least an intuitive understanding of the concept of [stable ∞-category](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344219/replacing-triangulated-categories-with-something-better/344221#344221). Trying to formally prove the axioms of a triangulated category from the axioms of a stable ∞-category is a fun little exercise that helps a lot in understanding what's going on...

Comment: @Denis I disagree, I think you just need to understand one example of what triangulated categories are trying to axiomatize.  The easiest is the category of chain complexes over a ring, considered up to quasi-isomorphism.  Anonyme: in this example,  the translation functor is just the operation of shifting a chain complex one step to the left.

Comment: I think this question is perfectly legitimate for MO, it is not opinion based and very useful for someone starting to learn homological algebra an homotopy theory. I do not think it belongs to MSE.

Comment: I think the question is legitimate. Neverthless, @Anonyme could provide a little more information on their background (especially for what purpose they want to learn triangulated categories). And I guess some of the axioms make sense for them; they should list the axioms that they find difficult to understand.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is risky to give a motivation for any concept in math and worse that of triangulated category that it is in a sense is a transitional concept form usual mathematics to mathematics up to homotopy.

In any case, I will give a few naive observations with the starting point that the prototypes of triangulated categories are basically the stable homotopy category and the derived category of modules over a ring. It is a good idea to have some notion of at least one of these examples to grasp the ideas behind the axioms.

Distinguished triangles pretend to formalize (co)fibration sequences that in a stable world both concepts agree. From the complexes camp, in the usual category of complexes a short exact sequence yields a long exact sequence in homology, therefore one needs a substitute that works after inverting quasi-isomorphims and very few exact sequences remain.

A distinguished triangle (I much prefer this name over the *exact* triangle terminology). It has to be a diagram like
$$
X \to Y \to Z \overset{+1}\to X
$$
Where the label "$+1$" refers to a shift of degrees. Why this shift? Consider the connecting homomorphism in a long exact sequence. In the case of complexes a triangle should arise for an exact sequence of complexes $$0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0.$$ From these one gets maps in homology $H^i(C) \to H^{i+1}(A)$ or otherwise put $H^0(C[i]) \to H^0(A[i+1])$. Notice that instead of $H$ one may use another homological functor. In topology, this is related to a canonical map from the cone $C$ of the map $A \to B$, to the suspension of $A$, i.e. a map $C \to \Sigma A$. The fibration sequence becomes a triangle
$$
A \to B \to C \to \Sigma A
.$$

This forces the category to be graded: it has to have an automorphism, called "shift" or "suspension", denoted most frequently as $X[1]$ or $\Sigma X$, with the triangles being depicted now as something like
$$
X \to Y \to Z \to X[1]
$$
The fact that the shift is an automorphism automatically gives a grading into the morphisms so you define $\mathrm{Hom}^i(A,B)$ as $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B[i])$.

Now let's go for the axioms.

**TR1**. The triangle $X \to X \to 0 \to X[1]$ is distinguished: because the (co)fiber of the identity has to be trivial. Think on the third point as a sort of cokernel, that might as well be interpreted as a kernel when you turn the triangle by TR2.
A (co)fiber or (co)kernel exists: any map can be completed to a distinguished triangle.
And finally everything isomorphic to a distinguished triangle is a distinguished triangle. I would call this axioms the *sanity axioms*, they allow everything to make sense.

**TR2**. The triangles can be turned forward or backward. I would call this the *stability axiom*. You can't tell a fiber from a cofiber or a kernel from a cokernel in this stable world. If you have a long exact sequence you can't tell where it starts, this axiom reflects that idea.

**TR3**. A partial map between triangles may be completed to a map of triangles, otherwise said, if you give two maps between the corresponding objects of two triangles (making the corresponding square commutative), one obtains a third one making everything else commutative. Caveat: this map is not unique, and in a sense this makes part of what makes homotopy difficult. To complete, I'd call this the *weak functoriality of cones* axiom.

**TR4**. This has a classical name: the *octahedral axiom*. It was introduced by Verdier whose motivation was to be able to take fractions. He applied it to go form the homotopy category to the derived category avoiding arbitrary long zig-zags, just simple fractions will work. Octahedra are in a sense higher triangles (one step higher in the ladder) and sometimes people look for even higher such diagrams. It is however noteworthy how far one can go with this four axioms plus the existence of arbitrary coproducts, like for instance Brown representability, Verdier quotients and Bousfield localizations.

A view of the octahedral axiom that is enlightening for me is as a version of Noether isomorphisms as it is depicted in the following diagram:

[image: Another side of the octahedral axiom]

Very roughly: $Z/Y \cong (Z/X)/(Y/X)$.

I should add that this is not the end of then story. In some cases one needs higher diagrams ($n$-triangles) and even worse, one would need some fix for the non-uniqueness of cones. The remedies for this are basically stable $\infty$-categories or alternatively stable derivators. But this takes us far afield into the world of advanced homotopy theory.

Comment: "Where the label "$+1$" refers to a shift of degrees. This forces the category to be graded: it has to have an automorphism, called "shift" or "suspension", denoted most frequently as $X[1]$ or $\Sigma X$" 
 can you explain what do you mean by shift of degree

Comment: @Anonyme I've edited the post with my previous comments, now deleted.

Comment: @PeterMay Of course, TR3 is *logically* redundant. However it may help as a step to understand the axioms. In my presentation I tried to emphasize the conceptual aspects. There are several ways to approach the octahedral axiom, and in my experience several people prefers different presentations to grasp it better.

Answer (score 9):

TR3 is redundant: it is  implied by the other axioms.  TR4 is confused by the initial octahedral shape: it starts with a square in which one side is the identity.  If  one instead starts with a triangle given by a pair of composable arrows and their composition and writes it as a braid, one readily sees that it is just describing the behavior of triangles under composition.  The description becomes obvious in the topological framework that was Verdier's starting point (he credited work of Puppe).   For the redundancy claim, the braid description, and the behavior of distinguished triangles under products, see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870801919954 or [https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/AddJan01.pdf](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/PAPERS/AddJan01.pdf).

Comment: I was very surprised by the claim that the topological framework was Verdier's starting point: my impression has always been that Verdier and Grothendieck's primary motivation was to abstractly understand sheaf cohomology in general, and Grothendieck's six functors in particular. Looking now in the introduction of "Des catégories dérivées des catégories abéliennes" I do find the following passage:

Comment: "Les catégories $\mathsf K(A)$ et $\mathsf D(A)$ ne sont pas nécessairement abéliennes; mais elles sont munies d'une structure supplémentaire, consistant en la donnée d'une famille de diagrammes définis à partir de la construction du cône : les triangles distingués. Les triangles distingués jouent, pour ces catégories, le rôle des suites exactes des catégories abéliennes. Les catégories additives munies de cette structure supplémentaire, mise en évidence et étudiée par Puppe [2], sont appelées catégories triangulées et sont étudiées de notre point de vue au chapitre II."

Comment: Other than this citation of Puppe there is no mention of stable homotopy in the text. I would say it is unclear to what extent Verdier was aware of stable homotopy theory at the time!